# Close window after printing - electron

Tags: javascript, electron

In my electron application I have to print a ticket silently.
So I am putting the content in a `new BrowserWindow` with `show:false` and I call `ticket.webContents.print({silent: true})`.
The issue is the window still opened after printing, and if I call `ticket.close()` right after print, nothing is happening and the ticket does not be printed.
I am asking if there is any way to know that the printing is finished then I can call `ticket.close().`

Comment: you're not alone ;) https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9712

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: Not yet. But as mentionned in the github issue above the electron team is working on a solution to add a callback the print method [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/10081)

Comment: Hello friend. I have the same issue and the only (bad but it works) solution is to make a setTimeout and wait some time (a second for example) with some like this: setTimeout(function(){window.close()});. And also giving focus with window.parent.opener.focus();
Hope this helps!